# SharePoint 2013 Search result when managed property for multiple line of text field with Append text setting

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, multiline-text-field

A List with Multiple line of text field column with Append text setting and list versioning enabled. We have created the managed properly for those columns to get expected search result, but in search result it returns only latest updated version value of that column the multiple line of text columns. Refer below screenshot shows three column of multiple line of text columns but only for one the column value (which was latest updated version) in search result even though all them had values in it.
[image]

Comment: Did you check whether it ran full crawl post the changes?